# File too large Failed to flush events

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to train a network. And the training breaks with an error saying that the file is too large and failed to flush events (tf.summary). When I checked file was actually 4GB+

```
2021-08-08 15:16:44.725004: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_kernels.cc:142 : Out of range: gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2; File too large
    Failed to flush 11 events to gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2
    Could not flush events file.
```

I am working with the delf implementation (Train script found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/delf/python/training/train.py ).
I encountered this issue earlier with an object detection model as well. As I remember I simply avoided the issue by omitting the event writing. But I would like to find a solution/reason for this issue.

I found questions about missing event file, but wasn't able to find a good answer for my problem. I would appreciate your help on this matter.

Update on what I have tried so far

- Changing max_queue parameter - Noticed that tf.summary.create_file_writer has a max_queue parameter with a default value is 10. So I assumed it gives the error failed to flush 11 events because it exceeds this default values. So I tried with different values 20, 200 and ended up getting errors saying Failed to flush 21 events, 201 events etc.
- Changing flush_millis - Changed this to a lower value to flush events more frequently
- summary_writer.flush() - The code did not have flush() probably because it is supposed to flush after flush_millis times), yet I tried to add flush() to see if it helps

Unfortunately none of this worked.

Full error stack from the initial error

```
    2021-08-08 15:16:44.725004: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_kernels.cc:142 : Out of range: gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2; File too large
    Failed to flush 11 events to gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2
    Could not flush events file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 486, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 410, in main
    desc_dist_loss, attn_dist_loss = distributed_train_step(input_batch)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 917, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3023, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1960, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 591, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Out of range:  gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2; File too large
    Failed to flush 11 events to gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2
    Could not flush events file.
     [[node attention/percent_25/write_summary (defined at /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/summary_v2.py:89) ]]
  (1) Out of range:  gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2; File too large
    Failed to flush 11 events to gldv2_training/train_logs/events.out.tfevents.1628396331.XX.9717.627.v2
    Could not flush events file.
     [[node attention/percent_25/write_summary (defined at /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/summary_v2.py:89) ]]
     [[GroupCrossDeviceControlEdges_0/Identity_2/_107]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_distributed_train_step_12517]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node attention/percent_25/write_summary:
 batch_images/write_summary/writer (defined at /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/image/summary_v2.py:140)

Input Source operations connected to node attention/percent_25/write_summary:
 batch_images/write_summary/writer (defined at /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/image/summary_v2.py:140)

Function call stack:
distributed_train_step -> distributed_train_step
```